# C# Get the work items in a TFS Kanban column

Tags: c#, api, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to write a small C# app that will give a notification when a work item gets dropped from the "Doing" column into the "Done" column in my TFS Kanban board but i cannot get the query right. Could someone please help me with extracting this information from the TFS API. I would also like to know the information on the item that has changed columns if possible (e.g. the Id, description and who it was assigned to).

My Kanban board layout:
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please post what have you tried so far and take a look at how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to apply Update 1 to your TFS 2015 deployment.  This added in [Query and display of Kanban fields](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-sep-18-vso) which means you'd just be querying for

- Board Column
- Board Column Done
- Board Lane

Unless you want to do something clever with the notification, rather than writing a TFS plug-in you could simply create a [TFS Alert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Work/track/alerts-and-notifications) to notify you when:

- Board Column Done = true